# Explicit match of template template arguments

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17, template-argument-deduction, template-templates

Consider this function:

```cpp
template<template<class, class> class C, class T, class Alloc>
void foo(C<T, Alloc>& container) {
    std::cout << container.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Function `foo()` accepts a `std::vector<T, Alloc>`, but it also accepts `std::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator>` in C++17 because `Compare` and `Allocator` have default values. Note `std::map` fails in C++14.

How can I make `foo()` only accept templates with exactly only 2 template parameters, so it fails with `std::map` in C++17?

Comment: Why do you want to? Why is the number of template parameters significant?

Comment: I have an overload of `foo` with 4 template parameters to match `std::map`, but `foo(std::map)` is ambiguous in c++17.

Comment: Do you want to exclude `map` or any `C<>` with more than 2 arguments? Why do you want to do this whole thing anyway? This looks very much like a typical [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Note that `std::vector` can have any number of template arguments.

Comment: I want to exclude all `C<>` with more than 2 arguments. It's likely a XY problem, but long story short, it is to update 3rd party code.

Comment: Does `C<T,A>` have to have a member `size_t C::size() const`?

Comment: Yes, I expect a container from `std` or some ad-hoc class that replicates their interface to some extent.

Comment: But why must it avoid `map`?

Comment: @Walter plase see the second comment. I already have a version of `foo` for `map`, so this other function makes the call ambiguous.

Comment: Maybe just turn this particular (mis)feature off until core fixes the partial ordering.

Comment: Implementing this via template template parameter is problematic and utterly unnecessary. Just don't. Use a single template argument instead and use SFINAE to specialize for particular containers if you need to. Or even better, write `foo()` to take iterator arguments -- the typical method for generic code in the STL.

Comment: Interestingly, latest clang does not compile this: https://godbolt.org/z/aln7cD Only latest gcc and clang (experimental concepts) do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I make foo only accept templates with exactly only 2 template parameters, so it fails with std::map in C++17?

If you want avoid that `foo()` accept a container accepting three or more template parameters (so fail with `std::map`) is relatively simple: you can follow the rtpax's suggestion or, given a custom type traits that say if a type is based on a two type accepting container

```
template <typename>
struct accept2 : std::false_type
 { };

template <template <typename...> class C, typename X, typename Y>
struct accept2<C<X, Y>> : std::true_type
 { };
```

and a similar type traits for a three-accepting container

```
template <typename>
struct accept3 : std::false_type
 { };

template <template <typename...> class C, typename X, typename Y, typename Z>
struct accept3<C<X, Y, Z>> : std::true_type
 { };
```

you can SFINAE enable `foo()` only if the deduced type accept two but doesn't accept three types

```
template <typename C>
std::enable_if_t<accept2<C>{} && !accept3<C>{}> foo (C const & container)
 { }
```

But this solution (and also the rtpax one) has a problem: what about a container that receive before two template types and after one (or more) template not-type parameter with default values?

Or two template types and one (or more) template-template parameter with default values? Maybe with different signatures?

You can add specializations for `accept3` to recognize the other cases but there are infinite combinations of type, non-type and template-template parameter, with default value, after the first two template type. So you have to write infinite specializations to intercept all cases.

This is a little unpractical.

And I suspect there isn't (in C++17) a practical solution.

Anyway, a full compiling example (avoiding three or more template types containers) follows

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename>
struct accept2 : std::false_type
 { };

template <template <typename...> class C, typename X, typename Y>
struct accept2<C<X, Y>> : std::true_type
 { };

template <typename>
struct accept3 : std::false_type
 { };

template <template <typename...> class C, typename X, typename Y, typename Z>
struct accept3<C<X, Y, Z>> : std::true_type
 { };

template <typename C>
std::enable_if_t<accept2<C>{} && !accept3<C>{}> foo (C const &)
 { }

int main()
 {
   std::vector<int> v;
   std::map<int,int> m;

   foo(v);   // compile
   //foo(m); // compilation error
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a template overload of the function that takes a container with three elements. When you try to use a container with two parameters it will work, when you try and use something with three parameters with the third having a default value (like `std::map`) it will fail (since either one could overload it).

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<template<class, class, class> class C, class Key, class T, class Alloc>
void foo(C<Key, T, Alloc>& container) {
    std::cout << "three arguments" << std::endl;
}

template<template<class, class> class C, class T, class Alloc>
void foo(C<T, Alloc>& container) {
    std::cout << "two arguments" << std::endl;
}



int main() {
    std::vector<int> v;
    std::map<int,int> m;

    foo(v);
    foo(m);
}
```

note that this doesn't work if someone inputs something like

```
template <class A, class B, class C> bar{};
```

since that will only match the three parameter option, so it won't be ambiguous

Comment: Your solution works with g++ but doesn't compile with clang++. I don't know who's right but, to works with both compilers, seems enough add a `class...` in template-template signature for the three case function (I mean: `template<template<class, class, class, class...> class C, class Key, class T, class Alloc>`)

Answer (score 2):

Add one level of indirection that uses a variadic template argument instead of two fixed ones. Then you can use good old `enable_if` to disable it whenever the count is not two:

```
template<template<class...> class C, class T, class Alloc>
void foo_impl(C<T, Alloc>& container) {
    std::cout << container.size() << std::endl;
}

template<template<class...> class C, class... Args>
std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(Args) == 2> foo(C<Args...>& container) {
    foo_impl(container);
}
```

See [here](https://godbolt.org/z/gzf3fx) how it works.

Side note: Apparently, [latest clang](https://godbolt.org/z/CZamiq) and [latest msvc](https://godbolt.org/z/nouhsz) do not handle it correctly yet. [clang (experimental concepts)](https://godbolt.org/z/Ab2tqD) does, however.